# How to convert Sum over partition from T-SQL

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql, c#-4.0, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have the following T-SQL Table, data, and query.

```
create table sampledata 
(
    name nvarchar(50),
    sampletime datetime,
    samplevalue decimal
);

insert into sampledata (name, sampletime, samplevalue) values
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 10:00:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 10:05:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 10:10:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 10:15:00 AM' as datetime), null),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 10:20:00 AM' as datetime), null),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 10:25:00 AM' as datetime), null),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 10:30:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 10:35:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 10:40:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 10:45:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 10:50:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 10:55:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 11:00:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 11:05:00 AM' as datetime), null),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 11:10:00 AM' as datetime), null),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 11:15:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 11:20:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 11:25:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 11:30:00 AM' as datetime), null),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 11:35:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 11:40:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 11:45:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 11:50:00 AM' as datetime), null),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 11:55:00 AM' as datetime), null),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 12:00:00 PM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 12:05:00 PM' as datetime), null),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 12:10:00 PM' as datetime), null),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 12:15:00 PM' as datetime), null),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 12:20:00 PM' as datetime), null),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 12:25:00 PM' as datetime), null),
('ABC1235', cast('2016/01/01 12:30:00 PM' as datetime), null)
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 10:00:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 10:05:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 10:10:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 10:15:00 AM' as datetime), null),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 10:20:00 AM' as datetime), null),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 10:25:00 AM' as datetime), null),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 10:30:00 AM' as datetime), null),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 10:35:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 10:40:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 10:45:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 10:50:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 10:55:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 11:00:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 11:05:00 AM' as datetime), null),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 11:10:00 AM' as datetime), null),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 11:15:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 11:20:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 11:25:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 11:30:00 AM' as datetime), null),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 11:35:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 11:40:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 11:45:00 AM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 11:50:00 AM' as datetime), null),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 11:55:00 AM' as datetime), null),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 12:00:00 PM' as datetime), 50.00),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 12:05:00 PM' as datetime), null),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 12:10:00 PM' as datetime), null),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 12:15:00 PM' as datetime), null),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 12:20:00 PM' as datetime), null),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 12:25:00 PM' as datetime), 40.00),
('ZYA4567', cast('2016/01/01 12:30:00 PM' as datetime), 50.00)
```

The query:

```
select 
    name, 
    sampletime,
    samplevalue,
sum(case when samplevalue is null then 0 else 1 end) 
over(partition by name order by sampletime) 
* case when samplevalue is null then 1 else 0 end as block
from sampledata
```

I need to convert it into LINQ.

I figured I'd break it into two steps (My actual query is more involved contain joins and where clauses than this example)

```
var list = (from s in db.sampledata).ToList();
```

Now I am not sure how to do the

```
sum(case when samplevalue is null then 0 else 1 end) 
over(partition by name order by sampletime) 
* case when samplevalue is null then 1 else 0 end as block
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it using LinQToSQL, becouse there is no straight convertion to SQL `over partition` constraction from Linq.

But you can do it on client side i suggest you this way:

```
int i = 0; //we need this for closure
var list = db.sampledata
    .OrderBy(x => x.name) 
    .ThenBy(x => x.sampletime) //order your data like partition function do
    .ToList() //get all from DB to server memory
    .Select(x =>
    {
        int block = 0; //logic of your block calculation
        if (x.samplevalue.HasValue)
            i++;
        else
            block = i;
        //return your full collection
        return new { 
                      name = x.name, 
                      sampletime = x.sampletime, 
                      samplevalue = x.samplevalue, 
                      block = block 
                   };
    });
```

As you can see sorting and selectiong logic will be on DB side, but calculated field `block`  will be on LinQ side.

**Another way** that may intrest you is to wrap your T-SQL query with *stored procedure* or *stored function* and map it to your LinQToSQL `DataContext` so you can call it.